# First input is just repeating itself

Tags: java, while-loop

I created a constructor for entering a persons' title whether its Mr Mrs Miss etc. And when the user entered something different like "mister" it will repeat and ask for the user's title again. But here's the problem, When my program ask the user for the title and when you entered first correctly it will ask the user again for the title even tho i entered the title correct. Like this

```
Enter your title (Mr,Miss,Ms, Mrs): mr
Re enter your title (Mr, Miss, Ms, Mrs):
```

but when you entered correctly in the second input it will go to the next question.

here the program

```
    public void setoptions(String title1)
{
    String title0 = "Mr";
    String title2 = "Mrs";
    String title3 = "Ms";
    String title4 = "Miss";
    String choice;

    while(!(title0.equalsIgnoreCase(title) || title2.equalsIgnoreCase(title) || title3.equalsIgnoreCase(title)
            || title4.equalsIgnoreCase(title)))
     {
         System.out.println("Re enter your title (Mr, Miss, Ms, Mrs): ");
         choice=keyboard.nextLine();
         title = choice;
     }
   title = title1;


}
```

thank you :)

Comment: what is `title1` stand for, and where is `title` declared?

Comment: A setter method should *not* ask the user to correct an error in the passed parameter. The caller should do that, and only call the method with the correct value. --- Last statement assigns the parameter `title1` to the field `title`. The code above that will *not* change that behavior, so it is meaningless, and just plain confusing that the loop prompts to re-enter value, then proceeds to ignore the value if correct. You probably meant for all the references to `title` in the loop to be references to `title1`.

Comment: You don't compare your options with `title1` but `title` instead, which probably is null at that moment. (I don't comment on the design issues here, that's already covered by others and you should heed their advice).

Comment: title is declared as a string i didnt post my whole program tho. @SashaSalauyou

Comment: @J.high I believe you're confusing those two. Anyway, consider using `Set<String>` to store possible options, and use its `contains()` to test whether input is correct.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas

Comment: Thank you Sasha and Thomas, I do get it now :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `title0.equalsIgnoreCase(title)` etc. should actually be `title0.equalsIgnoreCase(title1)`. In your case I assume `title` is null at first but when asking for the input you assign it the input value hence it works the second time.

Besides that you might improve your code by using a set:

```
Set<String> possibleTitles = new HashSet<>();
possibleTitles.add("mr");
possibleTitles.add("mrs");
...

//since the set internally uses equals() we need to store the elements
//and do the lookups in a common case (elements are put in lower case here,
//so we do the lookup in the same case)
if( !possibleTitles.contains( title.toLowerCase() ) {
  //ask for input, note that this should not be inside the setter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best in my sense is to use an `Enum` and a `utility` method to make it clearer.

```
enum Titles {
    MR, MRS, MS, MISS;

    public static List<String> listValues (){
        return Stream.of(Titles.values())
                     .map(String::valueOf)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And your method

```
public void setTitle(String title){
    while (!Titles.listValues().contains(title.toUpperCase())) {
        System.out.println("Re enter your title (Mr, Miss, Ms, Mrs): ");
        title = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
}
```